# In Django can I use get absolute url with if statements to refer to other apps?

Tags: python, django

## Can I use get_absolute_url with if statements to refer to other apps?

Another django newbie question:

My django project has a customer model that I'd like to share across multiple products that are each contained in an app (e.g. mobile, fixed).

Currently, I have this customer model within the mobile app:

```
# mobile/models.py

class Client(models.Model):
    client_code  = models.CharField(max_length=6, unique=True, db_index=True,)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=200) 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('mobile:mobile_list_by_client',args=[self.slug])
```

The absolute url yields a path e.g.: '127.0.0.1:8000/mobile/AAA001' to customer AAA001.

This is the mobile product model in the mobile app:

```
# mobile.models.py

class MobileLineIdentifiers(models.Model):

    client_code_1 =  models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name = 'client_mobile' )
    mtn = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=False, null=False, db_index=True)

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('mobile:mtn_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

I have Client as foriegn key in the fixed app:

```
# fixed/models.py

from mobile.models import Client

class FixedLineIdentifiers(models.Model):
    client_code_3 =  models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name = 'client_fixed' )
    fixed_cli = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=False, null=False, db_index=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('fixed:fixed_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

Can I simply re-use the mobile client model across apps using 'if' statements within the get_absolute_url function?

## What I'd like to achive:

```
# mobile/models.py

class Client(models.Model):
    
#....
    def get_absolute_url(self):
            # IF mobile:
                   return reverse('mobile:mobile_list_by_client',args=[self.slug])

            # IF fixed: 
                   return reverse('fixed:fixed_list_by_client',args=[self.slug])
```

I'm struggling with the 'if' statement references. How do I distinguish between mobile and fixed references here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the foreign keys backwards using `self.client_mobile` and `self.client_fixed`. You use these names because you have set `related_name` in your foreign keys. See the [related objects reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/) docs for more info:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    if self.client_mobile.exists():
       return reverse('mobile:mobile_list_by_client',args=[self.slug])
    elif self.client_fixed.exists():
       return reverse('fixed:fixed_list_by_client',args=[self.slug])
    else:
       # return fallback
```

Comment: thanks, that has helped. I'm just looking at the case where the client has both mobile and fixed products. Looks like the reference will now refer to the first 'if' that is satisfied. Is there a better way to be more discerning please?

Comment: Yes, the example above would use `mobile_list_by_client` if the client has both mobile and fixed products. I'm not sure what you mean by 'be more discerning'. The `get_absolute_url` method can only return one URL, so it's up to you to decide what to return if the client has both.

Comment: Thanks, now I can see how I could change the apps and models to make use of this - probably better to have a client app including mobile and fixed line ownership.